# Salesforce SOAP api clientId

Tags: java, api, soap, salesforce, clientid

How do you set the clientId when using Salesforce com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the clientId that is used for partner apps (that is part of the CallOptions soap header), then you can't set this in the enterprise API, only the partner API.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it by adding the header manually:    
    `connection = Connector.newConnection(sfConfig);  
    QName headerName = new QName("urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com", "CallOptions");  
XmlObject header = new XmlObject(headerName, null);  
header.addField("client", clientId);  
connection.addExtraHeader(headerName, header);`